# showing progressbar while function fetching data from database

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I have a button on this button click I am calling a function e.g

```
<button ng-Click=”getData()”></button>
<div class=”Progressbar” ng-show=” showProgress “></div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.showProgress = false;
$scope.getData = function () {
    $scope.showProgress = !$scope.showProgress;
    myRepository.getAllData();
}
```

This function is taking longer time to fetch data from Database.
I want to show a SPINNER while data is getting fetched.

But this “Div” is shown only after whole function has been completed.
I want it to be shown before the completion of function.
How I can achieve that?

Comment: <button ng-Click=”getData()”></button>

$scope.showProgress=false;

$scope.getData= function (){
$scope.showProgress= ! $scope.showProgress;
myRepository.getAllData();
} <div class=”Progressbar” ng-show=” showProgress “></div>

Comment: What is `myRepository.getAllData`?

Answer (score 1):

Set `showProgress = true` before loading data, and to `false` once data is loaded. For reliable behavior make `myRepository.getAllData` return promise, and then use its `then` method to hide spinner:

```
$scope.getData = function() {
    $scope.showProgress = true;
    myRepository.getAllData().then(function() {
        $scope.showProgress = false;
    });
}
```